# creating next/previous links rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

This is my first time here. I'm new to rails. I'm building a site that has PROJECTS and IMAGES, IMAGES belongs to PROJECTS.
I have a list action that shows all PROJECTS and when I click a project it takes me to the show. 
In the show I want to add 2 links at the top that take me to the previous and next PROJECTS.
This is in my PROJECTS model

```
has_many :images
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
scope :sorted, order(id: :asc)
def previous
Project.first.where("projects.id > ?", :id).order(id: :desc)
end

def next
Project.first.where("projects.id < ?", :id).order(id: :asc)
end
```

This is in my show action view

```
=link_to('<< Previous',{:id => @project.previous})
=link_to('Next >>',{:id => @project.next})
```

This is my show action in ProjectController

```
def show
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

I am using RAILS 4 and I get the following error when rendering the show view

```
undefined method `where' for #<Project:0x007fadbcc66878>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can FIRST and WHERE be chained together?
Please educate me !!!!

Comment: Try reversing the order: `Project.where(...).first`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
Project.where("projects.id > ?", :id).order(id: :desc).first
```

What you were trying to do was chaining the `where` method on a `Project` object, instead on a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object ('list' of `Project` objects)

Hows about another solution:

```
def show   
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])   
    @previous = Project.where("id < ?", params[:id]).order(:id).first   
    @next = Project.where("id > ?", params[:id]).order(:id).first 
end
```

And then in your view just see if `@previous` and `@next` are present (they can be nil if its the first or last project) and render the link/button such as:

```
if @previous
  link_to "Previous", @previous
```

This way you don't need any other actions such as `previous` and `next`

Comment: I understood the fact that I was trying to chain the where method on an object instead of an ActiveRecord::Relation. But it's still not working. I don't get the error message but now, when I hover over the links I see PREVIOUS is sending id?3 and NEXT is sending empty id only project/show. While the current show has a project.id of 1.

Comment: what didn't you understand then?

Comment: For some reason it's not picking up my current show id. If I write this Project.where("id < ?", 2).order(id: :asc).first it works fine. But when I give it a dynamic value it doesn't pick it up.